# Google map api does not load in page with large data (26MB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-api-3, timeout, pm2

I use nodejs with express to serve a page with 35000 data points, which consist lots of attributes in addition to lat/lon, using google map api (heatmap). It renders map correctly when hosted in localhost. However the map does not even show up if hosted on remote server.
Large portion of object actually rendered in `<script> *** </script>` means I really get the 35000 data from server. But google javascript api is not loaded so map does not come out.

There are some possibilities and measures I did. But none of them worked out.

1. pm2 server can not serve large page (which is 26MB). But it does in localhost.
2. server side connection timeout, since it takes longer to serve from remote and it works in localhost. However I used `pm2 start server.js --kill-timeout 30000` it still does not work.
3. browser connection timeout. On Safari I get message `Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost.` right after 5.5 second passed while no error message in chrome. The network manager is like this [Network Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy7cN.png).

Any help/idea would be appreciated. Thx!

Nodejs/express Server:

```
app.get('/map', (req, res) => {
        let queryData = `select * from table;`;
        let dataPromise = sequelize.query(queryData, {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});

        dataPromise.then(data => {
            res.render('map/map.hbs', {data: JSON.stringify(data)});
        });

    });
```

hbs Client:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    var map;

    function initMap() {
        var sanFrancisco = new google.maps.LatLng(37.774546, -122.433523);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: sanFrancisco,
            zoom: 13
        });

        var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            dissipating: true,
            maxIntensity: 10,
            radius: 5,
            opacity: 0.9,
        });

        plot_heatmap(heatmap, {{{data}}});
    }

    function plot_heatmap(heatmap, json_data){
        heatmap.setMap(null);
        let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        let heatmapData = json_data.map(element => {
            loc = new google.maps.LatLng(element.lat, element.lon);
            bounds.extend(loc);
            return new google.maps.LatLng(element.lat, element.lon);
        });

        map.fitBounds(bounds);       // auto-zoom
        map.panToBounds(bounds);     // auto-center

        heatmap.data = heatmapData;

        heatmap.setMap(map);
    }

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&callback=initMap&&libraries=visualization"
        async defer></script>
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Still does not know which part is the problem.

So I ended up doing multiple ajax requests with pagination to reduce the one time page load and it works.